# Variable name apk

Tags: python, file-io, apk

I have created a script that tests apk. Right now I am providing the name of the apk in the script. I want it to take the apk on its own, any file that has .apk in that directory. Can someone please tell what I should write in the required field?

Answer (score 0):

*any file that has .apk in that directory*

This looks like task for [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob), following code

```
import glob
apk_list = glob.glob("*.apk")
print(apk_list)
```

should print list of all files which name ends with `.apk` in current working directory

Comment: I dont need to print the apk list, I want the script to take the apk file as input. Right now, I am writing the apk name in the script, but I want it to take the apk file in the directory on its own. Thanks a lot, btw for your valuable input.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
import os

fileDir = r"You folder path"
fileExt = r".apk"
Apkdata = [_ for _ in os.listdir(fileDir) if _.endswith(fileExt)]

print(Apkdata)
```